# Powershell group labels in table

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a way to label a group of computers within a table in PS.

Currently I am running:

```
get-service -computername pc1, pc2, pc3, pc4, pc5 -displayname '*Random Service Name*' | format-table -property Status, MachineName, Name -auto
```

Now I want to add a column which specifies what group the computers are a part of, so let's say pc1, pc2, pc3 belong to group 1, pc4 to group 2, pc5 to group 3.

I know I would also need to define the groups previously but how to address them in the code? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `Select-Object` cmdlet allows you to add new [(calculated) properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx). You can use that for instance to resolve the service group name from a hashtable that you created before:

```
$group = @{
  'pc1' = 'group 1'
  'pc2' = 'group 1'
  'pc3' = 'group 1'
  'pc4' = 'group 2'
  'pc5' = 'group 3'
}

Get-Service -computername pc1,pc2,pc3,pc4,pc5 -displayname '*something*' |
  Select-Object Status, MachineName, Name,
                @{n='ServiceGroup';e={$group[$_.MachineName]}} |
  Format-Table -AutoSize
```